# Constrained minimum not-quite spanning tree?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I'm looking for some search terms/papers that I can read for a problem like the following.

I have some undirected graph, G, where there are non-negative weights between nodes. However, each node has an associated "state"/"colour". Changing any node's state/colour changes the weights between adjacent nodes.

I need find the set of colours that minimises the total weight of the tree, but I'm having trouble matching this to an existing known problem. I've considered duplicating the nodes,once for each state - but its not quite a minimum spanning tree problem, as not all nodes then need to (or indeed can) be visited.

Any ideas as to existing algorithms or papers for this problem?  I'm having trouble coming up with good search terms.

Comment: If we were just measuring the total weight of the edges instead of the spanning tree, then this would generalize MAX-2SAT, an NP-hard problem. I can't imagine that the spanning tree piece is going to make this easier. This is also related to prize-collecting Steiner tree problems (also hard). In your shoes, I'd try [a constraint solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver) and generate the cut covering constraints lazily (as in TSP with subtour elimination constraints).

Comment: May be ask here: https://or.stackexchange.com/